# Something in my Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS installation is running amok and filling my 450GB root filesystem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root

As the heading says. I've tracked down which file is growing to fill the filesystem, it's
/proc/kcore.
Here's a snippet of 'ls /proc'

{
-rw-------   1 root             root             140737471590400 Nov  9 02:54 kcore
}

I tried 'tail /proc/kcore' but it's obviously a binary file and wouldn't stop until I killed it.   Even logged in as root, it wouldn't let me delete it.   Heeelp!
Peter

Comment: It's not really a file on a disk.  `/proc` is a virtual filesystem.  By simply googling the file, I found this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170795/proc-kcore-file-is-huge

Comment: `/proc/kcore` being huge is not an issue at all.  Are there any real signs of trouble?

Comment: Oscar Skog:   On my system /proc is a subdirectory of the root filesystem - not a tempfs or virtual filesystem.

The problem is (if you look at the numbers) is that my approx 45GB installation has produced an approximately  400GB kcore file which only stopped growing because there was no room left on the partition.

Comment: And BTW most processes which write to the disk repeatedly faled after about 4AM Melbourne AU time because they couldn't write to the disk. 'no room on filesystem'

If there were a way for me to attach a file, I would attach the syslog and maybe the dmesg log to assist an answer.

Comment: That makes no sense.  `/proc` should be a virtual file system, I don't think it can even work otherwise.  There will of course exist an empty directory `proc` in the root file system, but that's just the mount point.   Can you run `du -h /proc` to check how much disk storage /proc actually uses?

Comment: ran du -h /proc. I got a loooonnngg  list of '0 filename'.

There's no point in pursuing the line that /proc should be a virtual filesystem. On my machine IT IS NOT.

Comment: I'm going to be incommunicado for a couple of days.

Comment: What is the output of `findmnt -T /proc/kcore`? Please [edit] and add this information to the question. Note `140737471590400` from the output of your `ls` is `128T`, not `400G`; but try `ls -ls /proc/kcore` and you will most likely see the size on disk (first number) is `0`. The problem with your root filesystem lies somewhere else. Try `sudo ncdu -x /` to track the real culprit; and if there is nothing suspicious there then see this question: [*2T file system full! `du` says only 70G consumed. Where is the rest?*](https://superuser.com/q/1810382/432690)

Comment: Run `mount | grep /proc` & post. On my system, it returns `proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)`. The `proc` type means it is virtual, not real.

Comment: Kamil maciorowski:  Output from findmnt -T /proc/kcore is:
TARGET   SOURCE   FSTYPE   OPTIONS
/proc          proc           proc          rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime

Output from ls -ls /proc/kcore is:
0  -r-------- 1 root  root  140737471590400 Nov 12 03:54  /proc/kcore

du -H produces a looong list of file and directory names all preceded by 0

Bib:   I get that "this is a virtual filesystem'  answer .

Comment: OK. Apologies to Oscar Skog:  Just because there is no 'tempfs' line for /proc output from 'df' doesn't mean that proc is NOT a virtual filesystem.

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts on my behalf. Each answer shed some light on the problem.
Kamil Maciorowski:   Thank you  for the tip to run (needed to install it!)  ncdu.
Using this utility I was able to track down the disk hog that was causing the problem.
It was a cp command to restore my personal data from a backup. I had directed it to the wrong (too small) disk, realised I'd done that and thought I'd killed that process - 
not so.

Now if I could finde a button which activates the 'Solved message, I'd press it.